# Hashtable Key and value storing in separate array list

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable

java code

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> gettingStatus = searchActiveAssetStatus();
        ArrayList<String> statusValue = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> statusCount = new ArrayList<String>();
        Set<String> keys = gettingStatus.keySet();

        for (String key : keys) {
            if (key.contains("Active")) {
                statusValue.add(key);               
            }

            if (key.contains("Abandoned")) {
                statusValue.add(key);
            }

            if (key.contains("Deleted")) {
                statusValue.add(key);
            }
            }
```

for the above i have stored Key in an separate array list (available), at the same time if that key exist in hashtable i want to store the value for that corresponding key in another array list (statusCount) how?

Comment: need more detail, unable to get what you exactly want.

Comment: @yogesh: from that Hastable i want to split the Kay and value and stored in an separate arraylist, from that above key values are stored in an separate array , can't able to store the corresponding value into an another arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right you just have to ask for the value of the corresponding key and put it in the list:

```
    Hashtable<String, Integer> gettingStatus = searchActiveAssetStatus();
    ArrayList<String> statusValue = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> statusCount = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> keys = gettingStatus.keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
        if (key.contains("Active") || key.contains("Abandoned") || key.contains("Deleted")) {
            statusValue.add(key);
            statusCount.add(gettingStatus.get(key).toString());
        }
    }
```

Or as Benjamin said just take `entrySet()` which makes it even easier.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `entrySet()` method instead of the `keySet()` method:

```
Set<Entry<String, Integer>> entries = gettingStatus.entrySet();

for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : entries) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Integer value = entry.getValue();

    if (key.contains("Active")) {
        statusValue.add(key);
        // Store value               
    }

    if (key.contains("Abandoned")) {
        statusValue.add(key);
        // Store value               
    }

    if (key.contains("Deleted")) {
        statusValue.add(key);
        // Store value               
    }
}
```